# Displaying a text field only if a particular value is selected

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've created a dropdown list that contains 3 values:

- date wise
- active students
- inactive student

How can I select a text field asking what the date of birth of the user is, if and only if the person has selected the "date" field?

Comment: Try tagging your question with 'JavaScript' and 'jQuery', because that is what you need for this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please provide us with more information, and take a look at the jquery ui datepicker.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

http://api.jquery.com/change/

http://api.jquery.com/show/

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

If you're not familiar with jquery, just take a closer look at the examples on those pages and you should be good to go :)

//edit - example:

```
  <select id="filter_selection">
    <option value="date_wise">Date Wise</option>
    <option value="active_students">Active Students</option>
    <option value="inactive_students">Inactive Students</option>
  </select>

<span id="text" style="display: none"><input type="text" name="text"></span>

<script>
$('#filter_selection').change(function() {
  if($(this).val == 'date_wise') {
    $('#text').show();
  } else { 
    $('#text').hide(); 
  }
});
</script>
```

...untested ;)